# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username must not be null or empty ,AbstractXMPPConnection.java:484

Tags: java, android, connection, smack

I am using **smack XMPP** in my app for instant messages. Everything is working perfect Except this crash occurring randomly

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username must not be null or empty
>          at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils.requireNotNullOrEmpty(StringUtils.java:468)
>          at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:484)
>          at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:448)
>          at org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager$2.run(ReconnectionManager.java:254)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

As far as I understand, Sometimes it just goes for logIn and couldn't find the Username. Which is a bit strange cause most of the time it is working perfect.

The Library I am using is

> org.jivesoftware.smack

Here are the methods I am using for connection

```
public void connect()
{
    Logger.writeSummaryLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "Requesting XMPP connection", true);

    if (connection != null && connection.isConnected())
    {
        Logger.writeSummaryLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "XMPP already connected, returning", true);
        return;
    }

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        private final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
        private int retryCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //KW: if network available but internet not available it will return
            if (!initializeConnection())
            {
                MyApplication.updateConnectionStatus(CommonEnum.ConnectionStatus.eDisconnect);
                return;
            }

            if (connection.isConnected())
            {
                MyApplication.updateConnectionStatus(CommonEnum.ConnectionStatus.eConnected);
                return;
            }

            MyApplication.updateConnectionStatus(CommonEnum.ConnectionStatus.eConnecting);

            try
            {
                //KW: on Connected listener we will changes connection status and send login
                connection.connect();
                Logger.writeSummaryLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "Connected to XMPP server!", true);
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "IOException", e, true);
            }
            catch (SmackException e)
            {
                Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "SmackException", e, true);

                // AI: SmackException happens when socket times out, which sometimes happen, so
                // retry after 1 sec.
                /*if (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES)
                {
                    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Logger.writeSummaryLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "Retrying connection after 1 sec", true);
                            connect();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }*/
            }
            catch (XMPPException e)
            {
                Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "XMPPException", e, true);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "InterruptedException", e, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "connect()", "Exception", e, true);
            }

            MyApplication.updateConnectionStatus(CommonEnum.ConnectionStatus.eDisconnect);
        }
    });
}





private boolean initializeConnection()
{
    try
    {

        SmackConfiguration.addDisabledSmackClass("org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.minidns.MiniDnsResolver");
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

        // START FROM HERE...
        // Unable to resolve host "betaxmpp.lynkapp.net": No address associated with hostname
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress);
        config.setHostAddress(inetAddress);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible);
        config.setServiceName(CommonMethods.createDomainBareJid(serverAddress));
        config.setHost(serverAddress);
        config.setKeystoreType(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        //need https authentication
        //so need to provide key store
        //android has default many certificates so need to authenticate using those certifictes
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        // when we provide any key store we also need to provide its algorithm
        String defaultAlgorithm = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(defaultAlgorithm);

        //authenticate keystore with null password
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, null);

        //with all these setting we need to create the ssl authentication context
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        //provide this authentication to our configration
        config.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);

        config.setXmppDomain(serverAddress);
        config.setPort(5222);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        config.setConnectTimeout(30000);

        // No need to send presence.
        config.setSendPresence(false);

        // We should use stream managment.
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);

        // Temp code to check if server handles it properly and have only 1 session.
        config.setResource(AppConstants.ResourceID);

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

        // Get callbacks for connection.
        XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);


        //Reconnect xmpp connection after every 10sec when connection is disconnected
        ReconnectionManager manager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        manager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
        manager.setReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.FIXED_DELAY);
        manager.setFixedDelay(3);

        return true;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "initializeConnection()", "UnknownHostException", e, true);
    }
    catch (XmppStringprepException e)
    {
        Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "initializeConnection()", "XmppStringprepException", e, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.writeExceptionLog(NewMyXMPP.class.getSimpleName(), "initializeConnection()", "Exception", e, true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, exception is on Reconnection manager.

I bet sometimes you are configuring Reconnection manager based on a variable related to your login status.

Move this part after a successfully login

```
   //Reconnect xmpp connection after every 10sec when connection is disconnected
    ReconnectionManager manager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    manager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
    manager.setReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.FIXED_DELAY);
    manager.setFixedDelay(3);
```

Keep in mind reconnection manager can just manage a RE-connection, not infinite try to first connect (example: start app while server is down). To obtain latter behaviour, just encapsulate your connect phase in a while-with-sleep loop.